# Jenkins: How to pause a parent job until postbuild of a child job ist finished

Tags: jenkins

I have a scheduler that makes builds of about 20 tasks at midnight and uses the same job recursively. However, when one job fails it has a postbuild job, that finds the culprit in svn and sends mails with the details to the culprit. My Problem is, that before the postbuild job can fetch the infos from the logfiles of the failed job, the scheduler already started a new one and all logs etc are deleted. How can i make jenkins wait to start the next job until the postbuild is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option in the jenkins post build plugin - named as "Block Until the triggered job".

This should work

Comment: that option is not there in post build

Comment: In post build there is a plugin called trigger Parameterized job/trigger another job. Select that in that there is an option to check block the build until the triggered job is success(unstable ) is also an option

Comment: that option is only there if it is selected from within the build

Comment: Yes the build section also has this plugin.

Comment: From the Documentation of Parameterized Trigger Plugin: ...This triggering mechanism can be used both as a post-build step or as a build step, in which case you can also block for the completion of the triggered builds. This lets you create a "function call" like semantics....

Comment: Yes thats what I said :)... Hope so this has helped you